# Why Image goes beyond Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a program for viewing images and I met with a problem that wide pictures go beyond the window.

I set the property "stretch" to "uniform" but it doesn't work with wide pictures. What can I do?

An example of this problem:
[image]

And if I expand window it will be this
[image]

This is XAML of image:

```xaml
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="0.1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="folders" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" TreeViewItem.Expanded="treeView_Expanded">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Cursor="Hand" Content="{Binding fileName}" Foreground="#FFF"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <GridSplitter Margin="-5 5 -5 5" Cursor="SizeWE" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowsPreview="False" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"/>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <Image Name="ImageViewer"/>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is sizing itself to its parent, but the `MinWidth="300"` in your first and third grid column definitions is forcing the parent to be wider than the window. `MinWidth` overrides `Width` if the two disagree.

If you change to these values, it won't do that any more except when the window is too narrow to be much use anyway:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30" Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I'm not sure what you were getting at with what you had: The number/* Width values (the [System.Windows.GridLength structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx), whose documentation meets the usual regrettable standard of WPF documentation) work in a not immediately obvious way. The following creates three columns. The middle one is sized to its content. The first one uses *one eleventh* of the remaining space; the last one uses *ten elevenths* of the remaining space. "`*`" means "`1*`". We add all the numeric values and pro-rate the available space accordingly.

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

That's exactly equivalent to this:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

It's proportional.

So your MinWidth values seem wrong to me, unless you have a truly enviable monitor setup. What I've given you will make the image area four times the width of the left sidebar, which is a rough guess at what you seem to be looking for. I like those proportions.

Comment: And about setting width "0.1*" and "*". In the beginning I hadn`t setted width. But soon I needed to set MinWidth. I setted it. But it wasn't working. And I found a solution of this problem on the internet. And that's why I set these proportions.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better than I did, but if there's something specific about my explanation that didn't make sense to you, please point it out and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: @S.Vladimir Your side columns had a minimum width of 300 each. The splitter has a minimum width of 5. So the grid *could not possibly* be less than 605 units wide. If its parent was less than that width, the Grid was not able shrink to fit the parent, so it overflowed the parent.

Comment: Okay, I realised that by my proportional if my first column has width in 300px, the third column must be 3000px. That’s why image that is enough wide can expand this column over the window. But I didn’t notice that because other images weren’t overflowed the parent. Am I rightly understand?

Comment: And this way decreasing the proportional solve this problem?

Comment: @S.Vladimir No. If a column has a MinWidth, that *overrides* its Width. You gave the first and third columns a MinWidth of 300. They ignored the proportional width at any normal parent size because of that. **Changing MinWidth to 30 fixed it.** I changed the proportional values so it would look more like what I thought you probably wanted -- but I could have been mistaken. Try your original proportional values if you like, maybe you'll like that look better. Those don't affect this issue in any way at all.

Comment: But if parent width is 700, wouldn’t the size of columns be normal relatively to parent?

Comment: If the direct parent of the grid is 700 wide, there's room for a Grid that's a bit over 600 wide. In your top screenshot, the one with the problem, you can *see* that the Grid is extending off the right-hand margin of the window: Notice that in the second screenshot, the Grid has a visible margin on the right. In the first screenshot, that margin is not visible because the right-hand edge of the grid is forced out of sight.